# logout user after successful AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, logout

I have an ajax code as shown below in which I want to logout the page after particular timeperiod of inactivity. The code below is inside the file **mno.php** (both javascript and php). My login/logout code is inside the file **mno.php**.

I believe I need to make changes at **Line A**. Instead of `{action:'logout'}`, I tried with `{'logout'}` but it's still not working. My login and logout code is inside **mno.php**.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])  && $_GET['action'] == "logout")  {
    unset($_SESSION['admin']);
    header('location: /abc/mno.php.php');
    exit();
}
?>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    let lastActivity = <?php echo time(); ?>;  

    let now = <?php echo time(); ?>;

    let logoutAfter = 10;

    let timer = setInterval(function () {
        now++;
        let delta = now - lastActivity;
        console.log(delta);
        if (delta > logoutAfter) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            //DO AJAX REQUEST TO close.php
            $.ajax({
                url: "/abc/mno.php",
                type: 'GET', 
                data: {action:'logout'},           // Line A
                success: function(data){
                console.log(data); // Line B
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line A or  in php so that page logout after 10 seconds of inactivity or whatever time we set.

**Edit 1:** I placed **console.log(data)** at **Line B**. On console, I am getting the **HTML** of my login page but the page is still not logging out. My login page code is inside **mno.php**. On doing **console.log(data)**, I am getting the following on my console:

```
<form action="/abc/mno.php" method="post">
        <div style='width:400px;'>
            <input type="hidden" id="user_login" name="user_login" value="1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                                <div>
                    <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="user_pass">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
</form>
```

**Edit 2:** I have replaced `/mno.php` with `/abc/mno.php`

Comment: Your PHP should be on a separate page for AJAX.

Comment: You mean, I should put my AJAX code at a separate place ?

Comment: @StackSlave Is there any error at Line A ?

Comment: I always put my JavaScript in my `<head>` using  an external `<script src='folder/file.js'></script>` You then use the script on the external file to send to a PHP page that send data back with `echo json_encode($objectHere);`

Comment: @StackSlave I have edited my question. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @StackSlave The error on network tab have stopped coming after modifications inside AJAX code.

Comment: Assuming the PHP is located at `abc/mno.php`, you're not `echo`ing any thing back for the `$.ajax({success:` method's `data` argument. Also, if that is in a form you'll want to `formElement.submit(funciton(e){ e.preventDefault(); })`, so the page doesn't submit to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have used ajax after processing the response has to be return back to ajax and now your code is sending back the html data which is `mno.php` because you cannot redirect from your php code .Instead do like below :

Your ajax code :

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    action: 'logout'
  }, // Line A
  success: function(data) {
  //checking if data coming from php is "success"
    if (data === "success") {
    //to redirect
      window.location.href = "login_page_to_redirect";
    }else{
     alert("error");
   }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(error);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});
```

Your php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])  && $_GET['action'] == "logout")  {
    unset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);
   //this will send back to ajax
   echo "success";
  }else{
  echo "error";
  }
```

Comment: I am wondering if AJAX will be sending request to PHP ? In your comments I can see that `// this will send back to AJAX` `// checking if data coming from php is "success"`

Comment: My page will load and it will not go inside php code because the condition would not be true. The timer will run and if `delta>logoutAfter` then GET call will be made. Let me know if I am right.

Comment: Yes when your condition will statisfy then only ajax will get call and php code as I have posted above will run ..you need this only or I have missunderstood your question?

Comment: My PHP code and JS code is in same PHP file which is **mno.php**. When my page will load then it will not go inside PHP code as the condition will not be true. First, it will go inside JS code and if its success and then AJAX will be sending request to PHP code.

Comment: You wrote that **//checking if data coming from php is "success"** which I don't think so is right. AJAX will be sending request to PHP.

Comment: what ever you will `echo` inside your php code will be send back to ajax as response. that only in above code i have checked if data is coming or not .

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact code and after the given time it worked. the ajax url is the file url itself (including php and ajax call).

**test.php :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])  && $_GET['action'] == "logout")  {
    echo 'logged out';
}
?>

<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    let lastActivity = <?php echo time(); ?>;  

    let now = <?php echo time(); ?>;

    let logoutAfter = 10;

    let timer = setInterval(function () {
        now++;
        let delta = now - lastActivity;
        console.log(delta);
        if (delta > logoutAfter) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            //DO AJAX REQUEST TO close.php
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: 'GET', 
                data: {action:'logout'},           // Line A
                success: function(data){
                console.log(data); // Line B
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

I get the 'logged out' from php along with the rest of content on the file.
so you should be able to execute your log out function.
Maybe check if your url is correct.

Comment: Do you know how can I debug the url ? I placed console.log(url) after Line B and I am getting error.

Comment: url is not defined.

Comment: I give a chance you've typed the url incorrectly. putting `/` at the beginning of the url goes to the root of directory. if the file is on the same page you should avoid using it.

Comment: maybe just try `mno.php`

Comment: well if the console is giving that message the ajax call has been successfull !
and url is not defined since its not a local variable. i think you have issues with your php code

Comment: just try `echo "something"` in the php function and `console.log(data)` in the ajax success. if the console is showing the `echo` output then there's no problem with your ajax call.

Comment: I am testing. Stay tuned.

Comment: My code is inside the file mno.php. The filename is mno.php.

Comment: console can only show the ajax code not the echo o/p. Correct ?

Comment: then in the ajax call just type `url: "mno.php"`.
and as i've said your ajax call seems to be Working ! since you are getting the success message that says url is not defined.

Comment: console cannot show the serve-side codes. only the output, so you should see what your  `echo` outputs along with the rest of the jquery codes.

Comment: I am getting the idea what is happening. My login page code is inside `/abc/mno.php` and on console, it prints the HTML my of login page

Comment: YES! ofcourse it is printing the page. you are requesting the ajax to get the page so the data shows everything in that page.

Comment: But why there is no logout happening then ?

Comment: try `session_start();` at the beginning of your php code.

Comment: I don't see it in your code above but if so then try 
`session_destroy();` or 
`session_unset();` instead of `unset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);`

Comment: I haven't pasted the complete code. I tried with both of them `session_destroy();` or `session_unset();` but its still not working.

Comment: I cant tell, could be a lot of things. check tutorials on how to make a login/logout with php.

Comment: I am wondering if you can see Swati answer and read my comments. Let me know if I am make sense.